# How should I refer to assets in order to maintain reference in production build in vue 3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, anchor, vue-composition-api

If I use `<a href="/src/assets/uitslagen/CHA.pdf">klasse A</a>` that works in dev but not in production.

I could add `import CHA from '/src/assets/uitslagen/CHA.pdf'` in the `<script setup>` tag but I don't know how to write the anchor link then.

`<a :href="CHA">klasse A</a>` doesn't work. How should I do this in Vue 3 composition API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the URL import:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#explicit-url-imports

```
import CHA from '/src/assets/uitslagen/CHA.pdf?url'
```

Comment: I still get an error then: 'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/src/assets/uitslagen/CHA.pdf?t=1705500301565') is not a valid name.'

Comment: @user1837293 do you use `<a :href="CHA">klasse A</a>`?

Comment: @user1837293 you are on a right track since you've imported a valid url

Comment: It works now. Code is exactly like in question, without ?url. Just stopped the server, new build, now it works...

Comment: @user1837293 yes, i remembered for PDF an url is imported. though i think it will work with '?url' also. i use '?url' just for not thinking what file types are converted to strings, data urls or simple urls